# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Been stuck on debugging this for quite a while. I'm trying to have a group of items change onClick but with the use of transform but 'style' is undefined. I've also included the Card component functions. Help would be greatly appreciated

```
import React,{useRef} from 'react';
import { Card } from '../components';
import { CardItemContainer } from './card-item';

export function CardContainer() 
 {


const listRef=useRef()

const handleClick=(direction)=>
{
    if(direction==="left")
    {
         listRef.current.style.transform=`translate(230)`

    }
}

    return(
        <Card>
        
            <Card.ListTitle> Continue to watch</Card.ListTitle>
            <Card.Wrapper >
                <Card.ArrowSliderLeft onClick={()=>handleClick('left')}/>
                <Card.List ref={listRef}> 
                  <CardItemContainer index={0}/>
                  <CardItemContainer index={1}/>
                  <CardItemContainer index={2}/>
                  <CardItemContainer index={3}/>
                  <CardItemContainer index={4}/>
                  <CardItemContainer index={5}/>
                  <CardItemContainer index={6}/>
                  
                </Card.List>
                <Card.ArrowSliderRight  onClick={() => handleClick("right")}/>
            </Card.Wrapper>
        </Card>
    )
}
```

Card Components

```
import {ArrowBackIosOutlined,ArrowForwardIosOutlined} from "@material-ui/icons";
import React, {} from 'react';

import {
    Container,
    List,
    ListTitle,
    Wrapper,
    ArrowSliderLeft,
    ArrowSliderRight 

} from './styles/card';

 export default function Card({ children, ...restProps }) {

    return <Container {...restProps}>{children}</Container>
  }


Card.ListTitle=function CardListTitle({children,...restProps})
{
    return <ListTitle{...restProps}> {children} </ListTitle>
}

Card.Wrapper=function CardWrapper({children,...restProps})
{
   
    return <Wrapper{...restProps} > {children} </Wrapper>

}

Card.List=function CardList({children,...restProps})
{
     return <List{...restProps} >{children}</List>
}

Card.ArrowSliderLeft = function HeaderArrowBackIosOutlinedSymbol({...restProps })
 {
    return <ArrowSliderLeft {...restProps }>
        {/*id allows me to style the icon directly */}
                <ArrowBackIosOutlined id="sliderLeft"/> 
           </ArrowSliderLeft>
}

   

Card.ArrowSliderRight = function HeaderArrowForwardIosOutlinedSymbol({...restProps}) {
 
  
  return (
    <ArrowSliderRight {...restProps}>
      <ArrowForwardIosOutlined id="sliderRight"/>
    </ArrowSliderRight>
  );
};
```

**Ignore**:
Been stuck on debugging this for quite a while. I'm trying to have a group of items change onClick but with the use of transform but 'style' is undefined. I've also included the Card component functions. Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you share the `Card` component code, and specifically `Card.List`? We need to see how it is handling the React ref.

Comment: Can we now also see the `List` component? From what I can see so far, you'll *at least* need to forward the passed React ref on to the `List` component. `ref` isn't a regular prop and isn't passed on vie the spread syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Function components like `CardList` don't have a ref property, only class components or DOM elements do.

You haven't posted `List` component's implementation, but let's assume it has a `<ul>` tag, and that is what you eventually need to manipulate its `.style.transform`

**`CardList` >>> `List` >> ul (this is the element you need to pass the ref)**

To pass the `listRef` all the way to `ul` from `CardList` you need to use the forwardRef technique.

```
Card.List=React.forwardRef(function CardList (props,ref)
{
     const {children,...restProps} = props
     return <List{...restProps} ref={ref} >{children}</List>
})
```

the `List` component itself :

```
const List = React.forwardRef(function (props,ref) {
           return <ul ref={ref}>
           ... the implementation of your List
```

Now you can pass `listRef` in here and it goes down the chain:

```
 <Card.List ref={listRef}>
```

**Side Note**: taking from Drew Reese's comment on this answer, since `CardList` is just transfering the same props from a parent component to `List`, you can simply assign `List` to `Card.List`, then only one step of ref forwarding would be enough:

```
Card.List = List // CardList component isn't used anymore.
```

The same thing could work for `Card.ListTitle` and `Card.Wrapper`:

```
Card.ListTitle=ListTitle
Card.Wrapper=Wrapper
```

Comment: I suspect that since `CardList` function component is simply proxying props that OP could likely use `Card.List = List` directly and cut out a forwarding step (*assuming OFC `List` also forwards the ref*).

Answer (score 0):

I too have just faced this same issue, and have tried to get my code working again. Checking similarity between your given code and my erroneous code snippet helped me fix the error.
Strangely, I have faced this error with a JSX multi-line comment in place after my element ([MUI](https://mui.com) `<`[Snackbar](https://mui.com/components/snackbars/)`>` element, in my case).

Error(s):

[image: Error Thrown]
[image: Console Log Warning!]

My code snippet looked something like:

```
      <Snackbar open={snackbarOpen} autoHideDuration={5000} onClose={()=>setSnackbar(false)} > {/* My Comment Here */}

            <>...</> 

      </Snackbar>
```

Quite similar place of JSX comment as your Card Component

```
Card.ArrowSliderLeft = function 
    ...
    return <ArrowSliderLeft {...restProps }>
        {/*id allows me to style the icon directly */}
                <ArrowBackIosOutlined ... /> 
           </ArrowSliderLeft>
```

Removing just the comment part `{/*  */}` immediately following an opening tag worked for me.
So, try removing your JSX comment or placing it elsewhere,and see if it helps.

Sharing it here just for my and others future reference. :)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30725129)

Comment: I know that this content lacks an explanation, but I have tried to answer by stating how this issue got fixed for me. Possibly, the JSX comment that immediately follows an opening tag gets incorrectly attached as the children of that element (based on the console error attached). 

And thank you for providing links and mentioning about adding bounties to a question, I'll keep it in mind in the future.